# A new block sealed in 6 hour on average in my POA private chain using AWS EC2. Why?How do I increase the frequency?

Tags: go-ethereum

As title：

My AWS EC2 spec. is ： 1 vCPUs, 2.5 GHz, -, 1 GB memory, 30GB SSD ,a free testing VM.

My init command is:

geth --datadir "." --networkid 15  init "./CustomGenesis.json"

and then,using following command：

geth --datadir "." --nousb --http --http.port 8545 --port "30303" --http.api "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --syncmode "full" --unlock 0b9331e020335d4cab5e00cea9de3xxxxxxxxxx --password "./password.txt" --mine --allow-insecure-unlock  --networkid 15  console

When I enter the geth console，I use miner.start(1) to mine.

The console shows these message repeatly:

```
INFO [10-29|19:11:05.775] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/home/ubuntu/chain/geth/triecache threads=1

INFO [10-29|19:11:10.450] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=5  accounts=1

INFO [10-29|19:11:10.765] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/home/ubuntu/chain/geth/triecache elapsed=1.970s
```

After about 6 hoers,a new block seased.

My genesis.json is belowed:

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 15,
"homesteadBlock": 1,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 4,
      "constantinopleBlock": 5,
      "petersburgBlock": 0,
      "istanbulBlock": 0,
      "clique": {
        "period": 15,
        "epoch": 30000
      }
},
    "nonce": "0x0",
    "timestamp": "0x5f9bcb9c",
    "extraData": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ad712c9171102d7eaf86d29589944411e3a70450b9331e020335d4cab5e00cea9de36b9c514e3a40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0x8000000",
"difficulty": "0x1",
"alloc": {
      "0b9331e020335d4cab5e00cea9de36xxxxxxxxxx": {
        "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      }
    },
"mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",    
"number": "0x0",
"gasUsed": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Comment: Can you add your geth command line ?

Comment: The genesis should include the consensus algorithm in the config section. Is it a PoA, PoW, etc ?

Comment: I add some information to  my question including command line.This is a POA. I test POW and POA both,the result is the same. I wonder AWS EC2 free VM is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem.

The key methods are fixed by：

First,the genesis.json is not correct suitable for my POA. The best method to generate genesis.json is using puppeth tool.

Second,every mining machine use its own miner account. Don't use the same miner account among mining machines.